# Remote WebDriver UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

I got this exception for all browsers. For example, I create a remote webdriver on chrome like this:

```
caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://myIP:5555/wd/hub"), caps);
```

And I got UnreachableBrowserException as follow:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`

org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

But I check my selenium hub at `http://myIP:4444/grid/console`, everything is fine, the node is stil registered. I then check my node at `http://myIP:5555/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html`, I still can click "Create Session" to create a session for all browsers.

I just got this exception today, it still worked few days ago. I am using Selenium 3.11.0, IntelliJ 2017.3, all drivers and browsers are latest versions.

I googled here, but I can't find a solution for this while my gird is still running. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
```

The current implementation of *Selenium* while invoking *RemoteWebDriver* supports the `ChromeOptions` and you can use the following code block :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://myIP:5555/wd/hub"), options);
```

---

### Update

As per your comment update the documentation at [seleniumhq-documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) is yet to be updated. Here are the relevant bytes from the [Selenium Release Notes](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG) :

- **Selenium v3.5.0** :

  ```
  * Start making *Option classes instances of Capabilities. This allows
    the user to do:
    `WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new InternetExplorerOptions());`
  ```
- **Selenium v3.6.0** :

  ```
  * All `*Option` classes now extend `MutableCapbilities`
    `new RemoteWebDriver(new ChromeOptions());`
  ```
- **Selenium v3.7.0** :

  ```
  * Migrated from using `DesiredCapabilities` to either
    `MutableCapabilities` or (preferably) `ImmutableCapabilities`.
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code works. But I have some questions if you are so kind to answer them. 1) I just check Selenium Documentation here: https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp, they still use DesiredCapabilities, which I followed and it worked for years, until today it doesn't work anymore. 2) As your suggestion, I changed it to ChromeOptions, it works actually,  but I still get 'Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`.

Comment: 3) I also change to FirefoxOptions() and InternetExplorerOptions() for FF and IE, but it doesn't work like it does for Chrome. Could you please  elaborate on this. Thanks so much

Comment: @Ragnarsson Check out my answer update and let me know if that answers your queries.

Comment: Thank you; it works with the new implementation. But I still still problem with FF. I will see into it.

Comment: @Ragnarsson Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement I will surely look into it.