# chromedriver: cannot execute binary file and SEVERE Forwarding newSession on session null to remote with ChromeDriver Selenium through Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I have a service that is using selenium to start a chrome webdriver using chrome `headless` mode. The application is launched through `tomcat8`. I can run the service without issue locally on my mac.

But once I deployed it to ec2 node through `AWS Elastic Beanstalk`, the webdriver cannot start properly:

```
28-Feb-2019 03:32:48.944 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [registerCustomer] in context with path [] threw exception
 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T18:33:54.468Z'
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-16-234', ip: '172.31.16.234', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.97-74.72.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:192)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:178)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
    at com.christina.insbot.factory.BrowserDriverFactory.createWebDriver(BrowserDriverFactory.java:64)
    at com.christina.insbot.service.InsBot.<init>(InsBot.java:86)
    at com.christina.insbot.service.servlet.RegisterCustomerService.doPost(RegisterCustomerService.java:93)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:685)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:13611/status] to be available after 20010 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:187)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:147)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
    ... 37 more
```

CATALINA error:

```
/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/webdriver/chromedriver: /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/webdriver/chromedriver: cannot execute binary file
28-Feb-2019 03:32:48.926 SEVERE [Forwarding newSession on session null to remote] org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess.checkForError org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 126 (Exit value: 126)
```

The way I start the webdriver is like this:

```
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        // "--headless",
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1200",
                "--ignore-certificate-errors", "--silent");

        if (useHeadlessMode) {
            options.addArguments("--headless");
        }


        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", EnvironmentInitialization.obtainChromeDriverPath());

        webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
28-Feb-2019 03:32:48.944 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [registerCustomer] in context with path [] threw exception
 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T18:33:54.468Z'
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-16-234', ip: '172.31.16.234', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.97-74.72.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

...implies that your program  was unable to initiate/spawn a new **ChromeDriver** service in *headless* mode.

Further, this error message...

```
/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/webdriver/chromedriver: /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/webdriver/chromedriver: cannot execute binary file
28-Feb-2019 03:32:48.926 SEVERE [Forwarding newSession on session null to remote] org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess.checkForError org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 126 (Exit value: 126)
```

...implies that your program was unable to execute the *chromedriver* binary so a **null** session was forwarded to the *RemoteWebServer*.

---

A bit of more information regarding the version of the *ChromeDriver* and *ChromeBrowser* would have helped us to debug your issue in a better way. However, you need to take care of a couple of facts as follows:

- As per [Headless: make --disable-gpu flag unnecessary](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=737678) `--disable-gpu` flag is not required on *Linux Systems* and *MacOS*.
- As per [SwiftShader fails an assert on Windows in headless mode](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=729961) `--disable-gpu` flag will become unnecessary on *Windows Systems* too.
- You are using *Selenium v3.8.1* of *'2017-12-01T18:33:54.468Z'*
- But your *JDK* version is much newer **java.version: '1.8.0_191'**
- Almost certainly your program is trying to spawn the *ChromeDriver* process as a **ROOT** user.

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u201**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.141.59**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.46**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v71-73*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.46 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Ensure that *ChromeDriver* is present in the specified location.
- Ensure that *ChromeDriver* is having executable permission for non-root users.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as a *non-root* user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### trivia

You can find a couple of relevant discussion in:

- [UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server with Selenium Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54824977/unreachablebrowserexception-could-not-start-a-new-session-possible-causes-are/54827351#54827351)
- [Remote WebDriver UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492697/remote-webdriver-unreachablebrowserexception-could-not-start-a-new-session/49493787#49493787)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solutions. I solved it yesterday night, it turns out that I haven't have chrome installed on the EC2 node, and also the chrome webdriver version is not applicable for the EC2 instance. I have sshed to that node and installed chrome and updated chrome driver, and it works.